# How to link two unrelated tables, through one table with common values?

Tags: sql, oracle-sqldeveloper

I am adding a commission percent column to an existing query. However, the commission data sits in a table unrelated to the main table (A) used within the query. However, these two tables have common columns/values with Table B.

I have three tables, A, B and C below

```
Table A     
Reference   Value_Name  Renewal_Code
1           A           N
2           A           R
3           B           N
4           A           R
4           A           N

Table B     
Reference   Value_Name  Prod_Code
1           A           0016
2           A           0027
4           A           0032
4           A           0032

Table C     
A_Prod_Code      A_Tans_Code    **Commission_Percent**
0016             Renewal        5
0027             Renewal        5
0032             New            10
0032             Renewal        5
```

I need to get the `Commission_Percent` from `Table C` relating to the corresponding `Renewal_Code` from `Table A`. This is the same as `A_Tans_Code` from `Table C` except that `Table C` spells out `Renewal` or `New` and `Table A` only uses `R` or `N`.

I have been able to pull through the `Commission_Percent` column into the output by using `Table B` for common values, but all values show as `NULL`.

I have also tried using a decode statement in order to link the `Renewal_code/A_Trans_Code` columns from `Tables A and C`.

```
( 
    SELECT 
          distinct c.commision_percent 
    FROM 
          TableA a 

          JOIN TableB b ON a.reference = b.reference 
            AND b.value_name = 'A' 
          JOIN TableC c ON b.prod_code = c.a_prod_code 
            AND b.value_name = 'A' 
          JOIN TableC c  ON a.renewal_code = decode(c.a_trans_code, 'Rewnal','R','New','N')          
  ) Commission_Percent
```

I need the correct `commission_percent` for `Renewal` and `New` business to come through for each reference. So far, I am only getting `NULLs` as I am having a hard time linking `Tables A` and `C's Renewal_code` and `A_prod_code` columns.

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: In your sample code at the bottom:  If you are going to join table A to C directly, you can leave out the intermediate join with table B.  However, in the code you have listed, you misspelled "Renewal" in your decode statement, and that's not gonna work.  So, remove all references to table B, fix the typo in the decode, and see what happens?

Comment: Thank you TheMouseMaster. I have attempted leaving out TableB and I am getting the ORA-01427 error.  I think where my issue also lies, is that within the script that I am amending, TableA's renewal_code is decoded to display as above. So essentially, I am trying to decode values from TableC to match the decoded values from TableA. Does that make sense?

What makes it more complicated is that I need it to only pull data through where Value_name is A.

Comment: try the following SQL, and tell me what the result is.  `SELECT distinct c.Commission_Percent from TableC c Join TableA a ON c.A_Tans_Code = Decode(a.Renewal_Code, "R", "Renewal", "N", "New", "OTHER")`.  Note:  I copied and pasted all table and field names from your example; if there is a typo in them, adjust as necessary.

Comment: Thanks! This version runs without any errors, however, still pulling through NULL values. Back to the drawing board!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This creates reproducible testing by cleaning up temp tables and re-inserting the data.
And could be a model for other solutions.

The SQL 'Select...' joins to a single TableC that has two parts to the ON condition-- prod_code and renewal_code  (instead of two joins).  Just remove the "a.*," to use it in your sql.  (the decode function was changed to use a subscript of the first char of the A_Trans_Code).

```
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#TableA') IS NOT NULL DROP TABLE #TableA
GO
CREATE TABLE #TableA
    (     Reference          INTEGER 
        , Value_Name         VARCHAR(10)
        , Renewal_Code       VARCHAR(10)    )

    INSERT INTO #TableA VALUES( 1, 'A', 'N'   );
    INSERT INTO #TableA VALUES( 2, 'A', 'R'   );
    INSERT INTO #TableA VALUES( 3, 'B', 'N'   );
    INSERT INTO #TableA VALUES( 4, 'A', 'R'   );
    INSERT INTO #TableA VALUES( 4, 'A', 'N'   );

IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#TableB') IS NOT NULL DROP TABLE #TableB
GO
CREATE TABLE #TableB
    (     Reference          INTEGER 
        , Value_Name         VARCHAR(10)
        , Prod_Code          VARCHAR(10)    )

    INSERT INTO #TableB VALUES( 1, 'A', '0016'   );
    INSERT INTO #TableB VALUES( 2, 'A', '0027'   );
    INSERT INTO #TableB VALUES( 4, 'A', '0032'   );
    INSERT INTO #TableB VALUES( 4, 'A', '0032'   );

IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#TableC') IS NOT NULL DROP TABLE #TableC
GO
CREATE TABLE #TableC
    (     Prod_Code          VARCHAR(10)
        , A_Trans_Code        VARCHAR(10)
        , Commission_Percent INTEGER    )

    INSERT INTO #TableC VALUES( '0016', 'Renewal', 5   );
    INSERT INTO #TableC VALUES( '0027', 'Renewal', 5   );
    INSERT INTO #TableC VALUES( '0032', 'New',     10   );
    INSERT INTO #TableC VALUES( '0032', 'Renewal', 5   );



SELECT distinct a.*,  c.commission_percent 
          FROM #TableA a
          JOIN #TableB b ON a.reference = b.reference 
            AND a.value_name = b.value_name 
          JOIN #TableC c ON b.prod_code = c.prod_code 
           AND a.renewal_code = SUBSTRING(c.a_trans_code,1,1)
```

Results are--

```
Reference   Value_Name  Renewal_Code    commission_percent
2           A           R               5
4           A           N               10
4           A           R               5
```

Code to put in your sql

```
   ( SELECT distinct  c.commission_percent 
              FROM TableA a
              JOIN TableB b ON a.reference = b.reference 
                AND a.value_name = b.value_name 
              JOIN TableC c ON b.prod_code = c.prod_code 
               AND a.renewal_code = SUBSTRING(c.a_trans_code,1,1) 
    ) Commission_Percent
```

Comment: Thank you donPablo. From my understanding, the above can be used in SQL, however, I am using Oracle Sql Developer. I am new to the latter. Also, the above tables were very miniscule examples of the large dataset that I am working with just for clarity of the output I am trying to achieve.

I wouldn't need to pull through reference, value_name or renewal_code. Only need to add a new column (commussion_percent) within an already existing script.

Comment: @Codash as I said above, Use the last SELECT statement.   "Just remove the "a.*," to use it in your sql. "  Then enclose in parens and name it Commission_Percent, just like in your sample sql.  I have added that at the end.

Comment: I see what you are saying. Thanks again for this!

Answer (score 0):

```
 WITH table_a AS (

      SELECT 1 AS reference, 'A' AS value_name, 'N' AS renewal_code FROM DUAL UNION ALL
      SELECT 2 AS reference, 'A' AS value_name, 'R' AS renewal_code FROM DUAL UNION ALL
      SELECT 3 AS reference, 'B' AS value_name, 'N' AS renewal_code FROM DUAL UNION ALL
      SELECT 4 AS reference, 'A' AS value_name, 'R' AS renewal_code FROM DUAL UNION ALL
      SELECT 4 AS reference, 'A' AS value_name, 'N' AS renewal_code FROM DUAL

      ),
      table_b AS (

      SELECT 1 AS reference, 'A' AS value_name, '0016' AS prod_code FROM DUAL UNION ALL
      SELECT 2 AS reference, 'A' AS value_name, '0027' AS prod_code FROM DUAL UNION ALL
 /*     SELECT 4 AS reference, 'A' AS value_name, '0032' AS prod_code FROM DUAL UNION ALL duplicate row excluded */
      SELECT 4 AS reference, 'A' AS value_name, '0032' AS prod_code FROM DUAL

      ),
      table_c AS (

      SELECT '0016' AS a_prod_code, 'Renewal'   AS a_tans_code,  5 AS commission_percent FROM DUAL UNION ALL
      SELECT '0027' AS a_prod_code, 'Renewal'   AS a_tans_code,  5 AS commission_percent FROM DUAL UNION ALL
      SELECT '0032' AS a_prod_code, 'New'       AS a_tans_code, 10 AS commission_percent FROM DUAL UNION ALL
      SELECT '0032' AS a_prod_code, 'Renewal'   AS a_tans_code,  5 AS commission_percent FROM DUAL

      )

          SELECT a.reference AS ref_a,
                 a.value_name AS value_name_a,
                 b.reference AS ref_b,
                 b.value_name AS value_name_b,
                 a.renewal_code,
                 b.prod_code,
                 c.commission_percent
            FROM table_a a
 LEFT OUTER JOIN table_b b
                  ON a.value_name = b.value_name
                 AND a.reference = b.reference
 LEFT OUTER JOIN table_c c
                  ON SUBSTR(c.a_tans_code, 1, 1) = a.renewal_code
                 AND c.a_prod_code = b.prod_code
 ;
```

The common table expression (CTE) is just to create the same values you posted (CTE is the part using the WITH construct).

Results:

```
      REF_A VALUE_NAME_A         REF_B VALUE_NAME_B    RENEWAL_CODE    PROD_CODE    COMMISSION_PERCENT
 ---------- --------------- ---------- --------------- --------------- ---------- --------------------
          2 A                        2 A               R               0027                          5
          4 A                        4 A               N               0032                         10
          4 A                        4 A               R               0032                          5
          1 A                        1 A               N               0016                           
          3 B                                          N
```

You may have to check the values in the rows you posted that do not result in a join. This also assumes there are no codes:code_name relationships that violate the rule of first letter of code name = code.